# How to hold automatically while accessing private route in node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt, passport.js

I,m a beginner in Web-development and I am trying to implement a login system in node by generating and storing the token and using that token to access a private route(...I don't want to manually include the token in header with every private request for authentication).

I am able to generate this token (by using JWT)while login but I can't figure out how to use this token to access private routes automatically without manually including the token in header.

Also I want this token to be used while the user is logged in and to be destroyed when he logs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After generating the token write the token to your user model in your db. You can also write it to the user's browser cookies.

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
  maxAge: 900000 * 4 * 24 * 30,
  httpOnly: true
});
```

After writing it to the cookies, the cookies will be available with each request. You can then access the token via

```
const token = req.cookies.token;
```

Use this token to grant access to the user or not.

When the user sends a logout request, delete the token from your db and delete user's cookie.

```
res.clearCookie('token');
```

Comment: Can you tell me a way to do this  without using cookies as I am trying to implement stateless authentication..thnks in advance :)

Comment: you need to have the token coming from the client to authenticate.